# Map domain web requests to local server

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, wifi, internal-dns

I have a mobile application that runs on android and I would like to map the API requests to an internal server on the network when the device is connected to a wifi network

The idea being that when we test the app we just have to log on to a specific wifi network and debug any issues instead of having to use different apps.

The basic idea is that when a device is on the wifi network and tries to connect to ***api.example.com***, a local server picks it up instead of public facing ***api.example.com***, but when the device is out in the wild it will connect as normal to ***api.example.com***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setup customized DNS servers (Unbound or Dnsmasq) to return different IP address of `api.example.com`, and setup DHCP servers to the customized ones.

In Unbound, it's `local-data`, e.g.:

```
local-data: "api.example.com A 10.1.1.1"
```

In Dnsmasq, it's `--address=`, e.g.:

```
--address=/api.example.com/10.1.1.1
```

Comment: i flashed my router with dd-wrt and used dnsmasq